# Streamline query to improve memory usage: OutOfMemory exception

Tags: .net, f#

I have a console app that connects to a remote dB and runs several queries.

I am using 64-bit F# to build the app.  I'm confident of this as this path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\fsc.exe
```

is used as the F# framework path during the build process.  Also, the above file path is in my PATH environment variable

Each query is structured as

```
query{expression}
|> Seq.toArray
|> Array.map (fun q -> {a = q.a; 
                        b = q.b; 
                        etc...}
|> writeToJson ("filePath")
```

I write to a `JSON` file as these query results are used downstream in the app.

I use `Array`s in the queries as I have included

```
<runtime>
 <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

in my `App.config` file.  [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx) suggests that including this

> ...enables arrays that are greater than 2 gigabytes (GB) in total size.

Unfortunately, during my second query of several, I get an `OutOfMemory` exception.

The query

```
    query {
        for header in db.CustomerDetails do
        leftOuterJoin row in db.MDR_0916
            on (header.PID = row.PID) into result
        for row in result do
        select ([row.APSci; 
                    row.Charter; 
                    row.VirtualSchool; 
                    row.AffIndicator], header)
}
|> Seq.toArray
|> Array.map (fun (row, header) -> {CustId = Option.ofNullable header.CBSCUSTOMERID; 
                                  IDType = Option.ofObj header.IDTYPE; 
                                  Name = Option.ofObj header.CUSTOMERNAME;
                                  State = Option.ofObj header.STATE;
                                  AcctStatus = Option.ofObj header.ACCOUNTSTATUS;
                                  Contract = Option.ofObj header.CONTRACT;
                                  ContractDesc = Option.ofObj header.CONTRACTDESCRIPTION;
                                  AcctMgr = Option.ofObj header.ACCOUNTMANAGER;
                                  InstType = Option.ofObj header.CUSTOMERNAME;
                                  InstDesc = Option.ofObj header.INSTITUTIONTYPEDECRIPTION; 
                                  MDR = Some {HasApSci = (row |> List.item 0); 
                                              IsCharter = (row |> List.item 1); 
                                              IsVirtualSchool = (row |> List.item 2); 
                                              AffRating = (row |> List.item 3)}})
|> writeToJson (Path.Combine(recEngTresorFolder, "rawCustomers.json"))
```

returns ~2.5 million results.  The `sizeof<RawCustomer>` to which I am piping the results of the query is `8`.

Does anyone know how I can prevent the OOM exception from happening?  Between the `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` and using F# 64-bit, I would have thought that would take care of it.

Comment: I would try avoiding using array.  Itty should help as seq is lazy

Comment: Keeping everything as a `Seq` did not change the behavior of the query or OOM exception.

Comment: btw, I'm not exactly sure how much space can be addressed 64-bit but it's TB territory. If you're process is 32-bit though you could get in trouble around 3GB. Maybe you are leaking memory?

Comment: the `sizeof` also doesn't  measure the actual memory your object takes up. That would be 8 bytes x 2.5M = ca. 20MB, which is actually the size of a 2.5M element array filled with int or a string. Whatever you are returning is much larger from the looks of it.

Comment: Oh, so even though `sizeof<'T>` will tell me how big an instance of a `'T` is, multiplying that value by the number of records doesn't indicate how much memory an object of `'T * n{Records}` will consume?  Good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your application has to be debugged and it's going to be difficult without having access to the database and your environment.

Just because you are calling fsc it doesn't mean it's 64-bit (although usually it is). The various flags to the compiler are set in the `.fsproj` file, usually via Visual Studio, but you can edit it manually of course.

[image]

For example I could create a profile that's 32-bit:

`<Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>`
 or:
`<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\ConsoleApplication8.XML</DocumentationFile>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>`

You could start testing in FSIAnyCpu.exe, which is the 64-bit version of FSI (should be the default on VSCode and can be set in VS2015).

1. Then you should make sure you can actually run the queries on the server, directly in SQL.
2. As a next step, I'm assuming you are using some type provider to hit the database, make sure the connection is cleaned up. For example use a separate datacontext for each query, and bind it with `use` not let, that way it will be disposed and the GC will clean up. For certain databases you can disable object tracking, and since you are reading from the DB this shouldn't matter anyway.
3. As was mentioned in the comment try to delay manifesting the result by using `Seq`
4. Finally when you convert to JSON, try to use some sort of StreamWriter, so it doesn't choke.

But in the end you will have to isolate the piece of code that causes the out of memory exception by careful testing (read adding some sleep and print statements.. ) and watching Memory on the task manager Of course it's better to use the Performance Profiler is VS2015 or something else like Redgate's .NET profiler.

As a starter you need find the cause of the exception in the query (or one of the queries) or the Json exporters.

**Add 1:**

This little snippet will give you an 8GB array no problem. So you can use it to test. There will still be a limit on the array length, at around 2 billion elements per dimension.

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let x = Int32.MaxValue /2 
    printfn "%A" x 
    let big = Array.init x (fun _ -> "aa") 
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    printfn "%A" big.Length

    0
```

Comment: Ultimately, I started with the most simple solution first: I changed my `writeToJson` function to, instead of writing the whole thing at once, to writing to a stream.  Although the process of running all of the queries takes >1 hour, I'm okay with that.  This is something that will run once/month at the most.